# Undefined variable error, when column exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
```

In lib/model_extension.rb, I have:

```
module ModelExtension    
  def generate_model_id
    self.id = "#{Time.now.to_f.to_s.gsub /\./, '_'}_#{self.class.name.underscore}" if id.blank?
  end

  def add_ticket_id_to_model(ticket_id)
    self.ticket_id = ticket_id
  end

end
```

In controllers/admin/lead_billings_controller.rb, I have:

```
  def create
    @lead_billing = LeadBilling.new(params[:lead_billing])
    @lead_billing.generate_model_id
    @lead_billing.add_ticket_id_to_model(ticket_id)
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:ticket_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @lead_billing.save
        format.html { redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Lead billing was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @lead_billing, status: :created, location: @lead_billing }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @lead_billing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

In models/lead_billing.rb, here's what I have:

```
class LeadBilling < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ModelExtension
  attr_accessible :ticket_id, :pre_tax_total, :post_tax_total
  belongs_to :ticket
end
```

In views/lead_billings/leadbillings.html.slim, I have:

```
- pre_tax_total = @ticket.lead_billing.pre_tax_total.to_f
- post_tax_total = @ticket.lead_billing.post_tax_total.to_f
table.table.ajax-table.show-mode
  tr.head-row
    th Pre-Tax Total
    th Post-Tax Total
  tr
    td = number_to_currency(pre_tax_total, :unit => "$")
    td = number_to_currency(post_tax_total, :unit => "$")
- if lead_billing.status == 'entered'
  = form_for(LeadBilling.new, url: lead_billing_path) do |f|
    = hidden_field_tag :ticket_update_type, "complete_and_generate_lead_invoices"
    = hidden_field_tag :ticket_id, @ticket.id
    .form-horizontal-column.customer-info
      .form-group
    .form-horizontal-column.customer-info
      .actions = f.submit 'Complete And Generate Invoices'
.clear
```

When I fill and submit the form, I get an error message, and this is what I have in the log file:

```
Started POST "/admin/lead_billings" for 162.17.182.1 at 2016-12-01 18:36:01 +0000
Processing by Admin::LeadBillingsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "ticket_update_type"=>"save_lead_billing", "ticket_id"=>"1473264666_2463856_ticket", "lead_billing"=>{"pre_tax_total"=>"100", "post_tax_total"=>"120"}, "commit"=>"Save Lead Billing Details"}
.......................
NameError (undefined local variable or method `ticket_id' for #<Admin::LeadBillingsController:0x0000000919e368>):
  app/controllers/admin/lead_billings_controller.rb:44:in `create'
  app/middleware/catch_json_parse_errors.rb:8:in `call'
```

I double checked the lead_billings table and it has the ticket_id column.

Any ideas?

Comment: in your controller `@lead_billing.add_ticket_id_to_model(ticket_id)` you missed to either set `ticket_id` or just say `params[:ticket_id]` on that line

Comment: Duh, Yes, when I copied the method over, I forgot to replace the argument with parmas[:ticket_id] if you turn this into an answer, I will credit you for it.

Comment: sure, updating as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your controller `@lead_billing.add_ticket_id_to_model(ticket_id)` you missed to either set `ticket_id` or just say `params[:ticket_id]` on that line